# Пытаюсь сохранить объект с данными(есть элемент массив), но не знаю как помогите. Спасибо за ранее

Tags: yii2, activerecord

В контроллере пишу такой код:

```
public function actionSurvey($id)
    {
        $model = new Results();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            try {
                $model->save();
                return $this->goHome();
            } catch (\DomainException $e) {
                Yii::$app->errorHandler->logException($e);
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', $e->getMessage());
            }

            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }

        return $this->render('survey', [
            'model' => $model,
            'id' => $id
        ]);
    }
```

Объект имеет такой вид:

```
backend\models\Results#1
(
    [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_attributes] => [
        'region_id' => '1'
        'answer_ids' => [
            1 => [
                0 => '1'
                1 => '5'
            ]
            3 => [
                0 => '10'
            ]
        ]
        'text_answer' => [
            1 => 'qweeqw111111111111'
            3 => ''
        ]
    ]
```

Структура таблицы:

```
$tableOptions = 'CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE=InnoDB';
        $this->createTable('{{%results}}', [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
            'region_id' => $this->integer()->notNull(),
            'answer_ids' => $this->string()->notNull(),
            'text_answer' => $this->string()->notNull(),
        ], $tableOptions);

        $this->createIndex('index-results-region_id', 'results', 'region_id');
        $this->addForeignKey('fkey-results-region_id', 'results', 'region_id', 'regions', 'id', 'RESTRICT', 'RESTRICT');
```

Я хочу сохранить каждый элемент массива из объекта ('region_id','answer_ids','text_answer'), сохранить в базу, но простой метод save() не помогает, у меня сломалась логика, то есть при сохранения ActiveRecord дает ошибку, что поля не валидны, это правильно, потому что эти поля 'answer_ids','text_answer' массивы, я хочу сохранить интежер и стринг, как это сделать, дайте направление, спасибо заранее.

Comment: Добавь еще структуру таблицы, в которую надо сохранить. Возможно охотнее подскажут.

Comment: Добавил код миграции таблицы.

Comment: исправьте заголовок вопроса

Comment: bemulima на что исправить, я вас не понял?

Comment: @IskandarXolboyev Не "Питаюсь" а пытаюсь и слово данныим исправьте на данными.

Comment: @bemulima я не русский, извиняюсь если сделал ошибки. Исправлю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему таким образом:
Контроллере написал:

```
public function actionSurvey($id)
    {
        $model = new Results();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            try {
                $dataArray = [];

                /** @var $answersArray array */
                $answersArray = $model->answer_ids;
                foreach ($answersArray as $questionId => $answersIdsArray) {
                    $dataArray[$questionId] = [
                        'answers_ids' => implode(', ', $answersIdsArray),
                        'region_id' => $model->region_id,
                        'question_id' => $questionId,
                    ];
                }

                /** @var $textAnswersArray array */
                $textAnswersArray = $model->text_answer;
                foreach ($textAnswersArray as $questionId => $textAnswer) {
                    foreach ($dataArray as $dataArrayQuestionId => $array) {
                        if ($questionId == $dataArrayQuestionId) {
                            $dataArray[$questionId]['text_answer'] = $textAnswer;
                        }
                    }
                }

                Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
                    ->batchInsert(Results::tableName(), ['answer_ids', 'region_id', 'question_id', 'text_answer'], $dataArray)
                    ->execute();

                return $this->goHome();
            } catch (\DomainException $e) {
                Yii::$app->errorHandler->logException($e);
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', $e->getMessage());
            }

            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }

        return $this->render('survey', [
            'model' => $model,
            'id' => $id
        ]);
    }
```

В моделе сделал таким образом:

```
backend\models\Results;
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['region_id', 'answer_ids', 'question_id'], 'required'],
            [['region_id', 'question_id'], 'integer'],
            ['text_answer', 'string', 'max' => 255],
            ['answer_ids', 'each', 'rule' => ['integer']],
            ['answer_ids', 'each', 'rule' => ['exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Answers::class, 'targetAttribute' => ['answer_ids' => 'id']]],
            [['region_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Regions::class, 'targetAttribute' => ['region_id' => 'id']],

            ['question_id', 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Questions::class, 'targetAttribute' => ['question_id' => 'id']],
        ];
    }

public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if (!parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
            return false;
        }

        $this->answer_ids = implode(',', $this->answer_ids);
        return true;
    }
```

В таблицу дабвил поля 'question_id':

```
public function safeUp()
    {
        $this->addColumn('results', 'question_id', $this->integer()->notNull());

        $this->createIndex('index-results-question_id', 'results', 'question_id');
        $this->addForeignKey('fkey-results-question_id', 'results', 'question_id', 'questions', 'id', 'RESTRICT', 'RESTRICT');
    }
```

Comment: П.Ы. Кто хочет, может добавить транзакцию и валидацию.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще правильнее будет не хранить `answer_ids` в таблице `results` а создать отдельно связующую таблицу, типа `answer_to_results` в которой будет 3 поля (id, result_id, answer_id). И затем настроить связь `hasMany` для получения этих данных из связующей таблицы. Подробнее в документации yii2.

Если хочется прям в такой архитектуре хранить данные, то вот самый просто способ:

в модели `backend\models\Results` в функции `rules()` убрать отовсюду поле `answer_ids`, и вставить строчку с правилом `[['answer_ids'], 'safe']` - теперь с получением/сохранением не будет проблем

в этой же модели создать метод beforeSave() (если ещё его нет)

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
  $this->answer_ids = json_encode($this->answer_ids);
  return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```

теперь перед сохранением массива в базу он будет преобразован в json и сохранён в БД как строка

затем нам нужно получать из базы эти данные, и хочется чтобы в `$model->answer_ids` был массив, который мы сохраняли. для этого создадим в модели метод afterFind()

```
public function afterFind()
{
  parent::afterFind();
  $this->answer_ids = json_decode($this->answer_ids);
}
```

теперь после получения данных из базы (например так: `$model = \backend\models\Results::findOne(1)`) внутри `$model` будет располагаться объект, в точности такой же как в вашем вопросе

P.S. это плохой способ. лучше изучить варианты хранения подобных данных в связующих таблицах и использование связей hasOne/hasMany

Comment: Первый вариант хорош, но проект маленький, простой маленький опросник, поэтому использую этот подход и таблицу.

Answer (score 0):

Желательно название таблиц в бд должны быть в единственном числе и их поля тоже. В вашем случае не results а result у этой таблицы есть множество ответов, значит надо создать отдельную таблицу result_answer, которая будет подходит один ко многим к result.

```
result
------------
id 
region_id
```

```
result_anwer
------------
id
resume_id
answer
```

И тогда при генерации классов модели

```
yii gii/model --tableName=result --modelClass=Resume --ns=\app\models
yii gii/model --tableName=result --modelClass=ResumeAnswer --ns=\app\models
```

У вас эти классы уже будут связаны между собой через методы Resume::getResumeAnswers и ResumeAnwer::getResume. Вам остается только перед записью запустить транзакцию, и заполнить все данные в классах и вызвать для обоих классов save(). Транзакция нужна для того, чтоб при не удаче откатить все данные обратно т.е. в контроллере в экшне пишите примерно так:

```
$transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
    try {
            $resume_model->save();
            $resume_model->ansers->save();
            $transaction->commit();
            return $this->goHome();
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        $transaction->rollBack();
        return false;
    }
```

Если уж на то пошло, что вам строго надо так по вашей архитектуре, то просто перед валидацией превратите ваш массив в строку json или serialize, чтоб данные прошли валидацию, напишите в модели Results:

```
public function beforeValidate()
    {
        $this->answer_ids = serialize($this->answer_ids);
        $this->text_answer= serialize($this->text_answer);
        parent::beforeValidate();
    }
```

и наоборот для показа для представления, как @Al Mr написал:

```
public function afterFind()
{
  parent::afterFind();
  $this->answer_ids = unserialize($this->answer_ids);
}
```

Comment: Имя таблицы почти всех фреймворков множественной форме используется, и из начально в Yii2 не правильно названо его таблицы, такие как: 'user' а не 'users' и тд. Спасибо за вариант тоже хороший, но проект маленький.